# Como converter comando SQL para LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho duas classes:

```
Produção
{
int id,
procedimento int,
quant int
string competencia
}

bpi
{
int id,
ini idProducao
}
```

Como converter o código abaixo para `LINQ`?

```
select ((sum(procedimento) + sum(quant)) mod 1111) + 1111 from producao
left join bpi
on producao.id = bpi.idProducao
where competencia = '01/2017'
```

O objetivo é somar todos os valores das colunas `procedimento` e `quant` onde `competencia = '01/2017'` e `producao.id = bpi.idProducao`

A soma deve ser dividida por 1111.

Ao resto da divisão deve ser somado 1111.

Essa questão de calcular pelo 1111, eu posso fazer via código.

Comment: vc está utilizando C# ou VB.net?

Comment: estou usando C#

Comment: você pode postar suas classes de produção e bpi tb, para facilitar os testes

Comment: alterei a pergunta acrescentando mais informações

Comment: Veja se ente Link pode lhe ser útil...
já utilizei esse software(LINQER), exite algumas limitações(ou não sei se eu estava utilizando errado... rsrs) mas pra mim funcionou bem... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47175/transformar-c%C3%B3digo-em-sql-para-linq?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se basenado nessas 2 classes você pode fazer essa query da seguinte maneira.

```
public class Producao
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int procedimento { get; set; }
    public int quant { get; set; }
    public string competencia { get; set; }
}

public class Bpi
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int idProducao { get; set; }
}
```

Linq

```
var query = from p in listProd
            join b in listBpi on p.id equals b.idProducao into _b
            from b in _b.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where p.competencia == "01/2017"
            group p by p.id into newGroup
            select new
            {
                ProdutoId = newGroup.Key,
                Soma = ((newGroup.Sum(x => x.quant) + newGroup.Sum(x => x.procedimento)) % 1111) + 1111
            };
```

Agora é só ajustar para a sua necessidade, provavelmente em fez de utilizar as listas q eu criei você terá esse objeto vindo do banco de dados. Como você mesmo citou, talvez seja melhor escrever o cálculo de `mod` fora na consulta, assim você poderia retornar a soma de qnt e a soma de procedimento separados e na sua aplicação fazer o resto do cálculo

Comment: fiz umas adaptações e funcionou.